# Python function not defined inspite of being declared in a class

Tags: python, class, methods

I have declared a function isPrecisied() in the class GradientDescent and calling it inside another function ( gd () ). I have created an instance of class and then calling a function with it (b.gd()) which contains the isPrecisied() function in the following manner

```
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        class GradientDescent:
            def __init__(self,x,y,yhat,alpha=0.01,pre=0.1):
                self.x=x # This is the x array
                self.y=y  # y is the array  
                self.yhat=yhat  # yhat is the array
                self.precision=pre
                self.alpha=alpha

            def isPrecisied(self,e):
                if (np.sum(e)/2)>self.precision:
                    return False
                return True

            def gd(self):
                self.beta=[0.0]*len(self.y)
                error=[]
                while True:
                    for j in range(0,len(self.y),1):
                        temp=self.beta[0]+np.sum(np.multiply(self.beta,self.x))
                        error.append(np.square(self.y[j]-temp))
                    t=isPrecisied(error)
                    print(np.sum(error)/2)
                    if t==False:
                        self.beta=np.subtract(self.beta,self.alpha*np.array(self.beta))
                    else:
                        return self.beta


                #take the average precision by 1/2*summition((y-yhat)^2)

                #B0(t+1) = B0(t) – alpha * error(of individual not combined)


        a = GradientDescent([1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,30,40,50],[11,21,30,38,48])
        b=a.gd()
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-744f30ba0c28>", line 2, in <module>
    b=a.gd()

  File "<ipython-input-9-13f85a04a1e0>", line 23, in gd
    t=isPrecisied(error)

NameError: name 'isPrecisied' is not defined
```

Please let me know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: try `self.isPrecisied()`

Comment: You have to call it with `self.isPrecisied`. That is a difference between Java/C# and Python.

Comment: There is no *global name* `isPrecisied`, no. There is only a method on the class, access that like any other attribute, with `self.isPrecisied()`.

Comment: Side note: `isPrecise` (or `isAccurate`) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It`s solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your

```
t=isPrecisied(error)
```

call for

```
t=self.isPrecisied(error)
```

Since you must always use self for calling class methods